# Is it possible to connect and query a BigQuery table from Google App-Engine (python) without OAuth2 authentication dialog?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I’m working on a Google App-Engine project which stores around 100K entities in the Datastore. Since I have to search in the string properties of those entities I have to find an effective way to do it.

After some research I found Google’s BigQuery service which looks perfect for me. I already imported the entities into BigQuery via the web interface but I can not connect and run a query on the BigQuery from the App-Engine code.

My App-Engine project has no web interface. It generates only JSON outputs which are consumed by mobile applications.

So, my question is this: is it possible to connect and run a query from the App-Engine python code without the OAuth2 authentication dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Simply use what's known as a "service account" as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials). Then, some simple Python code once you've exported `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to the credential file:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project='PROJECT_ID')
for dataset in client.list_datasets():
        do_something_with(dataset)
```

More info [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html#) too.

Comment: Thank you Graham. I already tried this but I always got this error message:
"from google.cloud import bigquery ImportError: No module named cloud".

I assumed that I have to "vendor" the google-api-python-client library into my project first, but I failed every time when I tried.

Comment: Yes, you need to install the module: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud`

Comment: Thank you again, Graham. You saved me countless hours.
I was pretty confused about this topic, but now I can see the light in the darkness :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick caution this is case sensitive
- to check the captalisation for 'Client';

```
my_bigquery_client = bigquery.client(project = 'my_project')
```

- this fails with an error **"TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"**

```
my_bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project = 'my_project')
```

- this works.